# Inverse of a function related area problem

Tags: functions, inverse, area

[image]

My solution is based on the following diagram which I will illustrate in details

[image]

Now ${A_1} = \frac{5}{4};{A_3} = 1$

$g\left( {2x} \right) = 2f\left( x \right)$

$g\left( 2 \right) = 2f\left( 1 \right) = 2 \times 1 = 2$

$g\left( 4 \right) = 2f\left( 2 \right)$

$\int\limits_1^8 {xf'\left( x \right)dx}  = \left. {xf\left( x \right)} \right|_1^8 - \int\limits_1^8 {\frac{d}{{dx}}x\left( {\int {f'\left( x \right)dx} } \right)dx} $

$\int\limits_1^8 {xf'\left( x \right)dx}  = 8f\left( 8 \right) - f\left( 1 \right) - \int\limits_1^8 {f\left( x \right)dx} $

Not able to proceed from here

Comment: $f(x)$ is not a function...

Comment: Though it is not defined but it is an increasing function as mentioned in the question

Comment: I just mention that $x\mapsto f(x)$ or $f$ are functions but $f(x)$ is just a number

Comment: $\small g(2)=2 \implies f(g(2))=f(2) \implies f(2)=2$. So, $\small g(4)=2f(2)=4$. Again, this implies $\small f(4)=4$. Continuing, you'd get $\small f(1)=g(1)=1, f(2)=g(2)=2, \ldots , f(8)=g(8)=8$. Also, $\small f'(x)= g'(2x)$ and $\small \int_{1}^8 x f'(x) dx =\int_{1}^8 g(f(x)) f'(x) dx=\int_{f(1)}^{f(8)} g(u) du$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Lemma:** If $f(x)$ is a continuous and increasing function and $a<b$, then:
> $$ \int_{a}^{b} f(x)\,dx + \int_{f(a)}^{f(b)}f^{-1}(x)\,dx = b\, f(b)-a\, f(a). $$

To prove it, you just need to draw a picture or look at [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_inverse_functions).

Now, following my comment, required integral = $ \displaystyle \int_{1}^8 x f'(x) dx= \int_{1}^8 g(x) dx=I\quad $  (say)

And, $\;f(n)=g(n)=n\;$ for $\; n=1,2,4,8.$

Using the above lemma on the given function $f$, we have

\begin{align} 
&\int_{1}^{2} f(x) dx+\int_{f(1)}^{f(2)} g(x) dx=2f(2)-f(1)\\
\implies & \frac5{4} + \int_{1}^{2} g(x) dx = 3\\
\implies & \int_{1}^{2} g(x) dx=\frac7{4} \tag{1}
\end{align}

Now, $\;2f(x)=g(2x)\:$ and $\: \displaystyle\int_{1}^{2} f(x) dx=\frac5{4}$
\begin{align}
\implies & \frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{2} g(2x) dx=\frac5{4}\\
\implies & \frac{1}{4}\int_{2x=2}^{2x=4} g(2x) d(2x)=\frac5{4}\\
\implies & \frac{1}{4}\int_{2}^{4} g(x) dx=\frac5{4}\\
\implies &\int_{2}^{4} g(x) dx=5 \tag{2}
\end{align}

Again using the lemma on $f$, we have
\begin{align} &\int_{2}^{4} f(x) dx+\int_{f(2)}^{f(4)} g(x) dx=4f(4)-2f(2)\\
\implies & \int_{2}^{4} f(x) dx + \int_{2}^{4} g(x) dx = 16-4\\
\implies & \int_{2}^{4} f(x) dx=12-5=7 \qquad \text{using (2)}
\end{align}

Again, $\;2f(x)=g(2x)\:$ and $\: \displaystyle \int_{2}^{4} f(x) dx=7$
\begin{align}
\implies & \frac{1}{2}\int_{2}^{4} g(2x) dx=7\\
\implies & \frac{1}{4}\int_{2x=4}^{2x=8} g(2x) d(2x)=7\\
\implies & \frac{1}{4}\int_{4}^{8} g(x) dx=7\\
\implies &\int_{4}^{8} g(x) dx=28 \tag{3}
\end{align}

From $(1), (2)$ and $(3)$

\begin{align} I&=\int_{1}^8 g(x) dx\\
&= \int_{1}^2 g(x) dx+\int_{2}^4 g(x) dx+\int_{4}^8 g(x) dx\\
&= \frac7{4} + 5 +28\\
&= \frac{139}4
\end{align}

Since, $\text{HCF}(139,4)=1\;$ required answer is $139+4=143$.

Comment: You can use the lemma again to evaluate $\int_{4}^{8} f(x)dx$ and then find $\int_{1}^{8} f(x)dx$ to substitute in your equation $\int_{1}^{8} x f'(x) dx= 63- \int_{1}^{8} f(x)dx$.